# Apply png image with transparent background to row if cells has a value

Tags: image, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, scripting

I am working on a google sheet and I would like to implement a functionality that works showing a picture if a cell has a certain value.

In detail, if a cell is equal to "reserved", I would like to show a png file with a transparent background that covers the row.
Since it has a transparent background, users will still be able to see the text of the cells under the image.

Is there any viable way to achieve this result in a Google sheet?

[image]

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. I think that in order to put an image over the cell, it is required to use Google Apps Script. How about this? 2. About `if a cell is equal to "reserved", I would like to show a png file with a transparent background that covers the row.`, in this case, when a cell was modified to `reserved`, you want to put the image over the row. Is my understanding correct? 3. Can I ask you about the effect for putting the transparent image over the row?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! 
The point is that the value of the cell is filled with import query function. So, there is no problem to use Google Apps Script but my understanding is that the trigger cannot be on edit (I guess it wouldn't work given what I explained). 
2. your understanding is correct.  
3. the image should be put over the row (extent up to 6 columns). The effect should be like this: https://prnt.sc/u0dflk (same image but with transparent background so users can see the cells under the image)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your sample image, I could understand that you wanted to put the watermark to the cells. In this case, it is required to use Google Apps Script. About `The point is that the value of the cell is filled with import query function.`, for example, how about the following 2 patterns. 1. If the cell is updated with the formulas by manually modifying a cell, the cell might be able to be used for OnEdit event trigger. 2. How about using the time-driven trigger? In this case, the cell can be monitored by the script. And when the cell was changed, the image can be put.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tanaike! Do you know where I can find a suitable code that can fit for this purpose? 
I understand that once it is programmed, I should just schedule the script to run every X minutes, correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I think that it is difficult to find the script which directly achieves your goal. So in this case, it is required to prepare the script. But I cannot understand about your actual situation from your question. Unfortunately, when I try to prepare the sample script, the information for doing it is not enough for me from your question. So in the current stage, I cannot prepare the sample script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Are you still looking for the solution of your this question?

Answer (score 1):

with formula-only, you can do only:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="xxx", IMAGE("https://i.imgur.com/PtqTEwM.png", 1), ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! is it possible to apply the watermark to cover also the other cells in the row without replacing the text (in your example B2; C2;D2;E2)?

Comment: unfortunately thats not possible with formula